# Indexed properties are getting duplicated struts2 on form submission

Tags: struts2

I need to add/edit/delete the table of objects in struts2. When I submit the form, I am getting objects duplicated.

Let me know where I made a mistake.

This is my code:

```
<s:form action="addPromotionLineItems" id="promotionLineItemsAddFormId">
    <display:table id="data"
        name="lstPromotionLineItems" sort="external" uid="row" htmlId="rowid"
        class="tborder" excludedParams="*" style="width:100%" export="false">
        <display:column titleKey="table.title.material" style="width:100px">
            <s:property value="%{#attr.row.materialCode}" />
            <s:hidden
                name="lstPromotionLineItems(%{#attr.row_rowNum-1}).promotionLineItemId"
                value="%{#attr.row.promotionLineItemId}" />
            <s:hidden
                name="lstPromotionLineItems(%{#attr.row_rowNum-1}).materialCode"
                value="%{#attr.row.materialCode}" />
            <s:hidden
                name="lstPromotionLineItems(%{#attr.row_rowNum-1}).material.description"
                value="%{#attr.row.material.description}" />
            <s:hidden
                name="lstPromotionLineItems(%{#attr.row_rowNum-1}).programId"
                value="%{#attr.row.programId}" />
        </display:column>
        <display:column property="material.description"
            titleKey="table.title.materialdesc" />

</s:form>



function refreshTableRecords(url,formNameId,resultId)
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: url,
        data:$('#'+formNameId).serialize(),
        success : function(response) {
            $('#'+resultId).html(response); 
            },
            error:function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
}
```

I have this content in jQuery ui modal popup.

Comment: can you describe what exactly you mean by duplicate object?

Comment: what ever info showing in the 0th index, when i submit the action i am getting that in 0,1th index positions.

Answer (score 0):

I think when mapping to collection data in struts the syntax is not:

```
name="lstPromotionLineItems(%{#attr.row_rowNum-1}).promotionLineItemId"
```

rather:

```
name="lstPromotionLineItems[%{#attr.row_rowNum-1}].promotionLineItemId"
```

There is a slight difference in the bracketing around the row_num attribute in the input name.